# I wish I could done(do something)

Tags: past-tense, wish

Which sentence is correct 1 or 2 ? First sentence is correct in English Grammar In Use Book at Unit 41. But i didn't understand why they didn't use heard instead of hear.

> 1. I **hear** the party was great. I wish I could have gone.
> 2. I **heard** the party was great. I wish I could have gone.

Comment: They are both grammatical. Without more context, there is no way of knowing if the book was after something specific.

Comment: I am confused with the party "was" great(past tense) but "i hear" is present tense,

Comment: I hear (now) the party was (in the past) great.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with mixing tenses in some constructions. This is one of them. This is similar to *I keep hearing the party was great* or *people tell me the party was great*. It could also start with a future tense: *I'm sure people are going to tell me the party was great.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason Bassford and Michael Harvey mention, the time frame of one part of a sentence does not have to be the same as the time frame of another part of the sentence.  This is particularly true when talking about *reported* speech or events.  The event can be at any time, and the report about the event can be at any time.  For example:

> I **hear/heard** your party **was** a big success.

Did I hear the report on the party just now?  Or did I hear about it in the past?  Both make sense, depending on what you want to say.

This can also be true for current or future events:

> I **saw** (in the past) that the big convention downtown **has** (currently) so many people trying to get in that they **have** (ongoing) to turn them away.
>
> I **see** (just now) that the President **will make** (in the future) a speech in New York tomorrow afternoon.

Not all combinations will make sense, of course.  The point is that the two parts of the sentence have independent time frames.